# Special process for calculating parameters in Google Data Studio

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, looker-studio

I want to do a linear regression in Data Studio. I don't know if there is something already existing (I've looked ans it doesn't seem like there is).
What I want is not plotting a linear Regression in a graph but to obtain the Linear regression's coefficients to then make predictions on some user-defined input parameters.

I more or less know how to code the linear regression function in JS. Is there a way to create a field which would take some parameters as an Input and a returns the output JS custom process (involves looping)? I'm not particularly attached to the whole JS process solution if someone has an answer that solves my problem I'm open to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [community viz](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization) in Data Studio to do this.

Easiest way to do it would be to first assume:

- you have a blank HTML page.
- your dependent and independent variables are in JS arrays.
- you are creating a single page JS application independent of Data Studio.

Starting from there,

1. write the entire code in JS to calculate the parameters
2. surface the parameters using JS created DOM elements
3. use JS to create input elements to take user input of dependent variables
4. use user input and parameters to make prediction and surface that

So essentially you will end you with a single page JS application. Once this is ready, you can wrap this in the Community Viz framework, link the arrays to the data form Data Studio, and then use the viz in your reports.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this way. As I have more of a DataScientist background (proficient in  Python) in your opinion does this way need confirmed JS programming skills ?
I need to give a rough estimate of the time needed...

Comment: I think if you are proficient in python the only things you would need are 1) understanding of HTML DOM elements and 2) how to modify them using JS. Nothing you can't pick up in a day or two.